# How can i set the context of parent activity as the listener for recyclerview which is in the fragment of that activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, fragment, listener

Main activity have a fragment and that fragment have a recyclerview.
ok everything is fine.
but now im trying to set main activity as the lister for recyclerview

i tried this inside fragment class but its not working

```
myRecyclerView.setClickListener(getActivity());
```

any idea please?

Comment: Can you try with Hilt (DI)?

Comment: sorry, but what's that

Comment: This is not the right way . If `recyclerView` attached with Fragment the all the listener should in the Fragment not in `Activity` . `Activity` can have ample number of fragments you can have it this way .

Comment: ok i implement that already but now again im not able to set the lister with the fragment, i tried this myRecyclerView.setClickListener(getContext()); and this time fragment itself is implementing the listener but it shows error/red line on getContext()

Answer (score 0):

Finally this worked for me

```
myRecyclerView.setClickListener((MyRecyclerView.onItemClickListener) getActivity());
```

here MyRecyclerView is adapter class in which i have defined the interface onItemClickListener, and MainActivity implements that listener.